# How do I deal with IEnumerable in F#?

Tags: f#

There are quite a few legacy interfaces that get collections of entities in form of plain `IEnumerable`. Commonly one would do `foreach(CertainTypeWeSureItemIs item in items)` in C# casting objects to whatever type they want as they go. IEnumerable doesn't translate directly to a sequence. Wrapping it in `seq { for x in xs -> x }` doesn't help much either because it gets `seq{obj}`. So how do I do this in F#?

Answer (score 22):

Use `Seq.cast<T>`:

```
let al = new System.Collections.ArrayList()
al.Add(1) |> ignore
al.Add(2) |> ignore
al |> Seq.cast<int> |> Seq.iter(printf "%i")
```

Comment: This does not solve anything for me. If I cast, I get error IEnumerable<string> is not compatible with IEnumerable. How do I force it to type "string list"?

Comment: @Diana - if you have an `IEnumerable` you want to convert into a `string list` you can use `List.ofSeq` e.g. `s |> Seq.cast<string> |> List.ofSeq`. If your problem is more complex than this, please create a new question with the details.